# MEF Exporting From Pre-existing attribute

Tags: c#, mef

I'm building a plugin manager using MEF, and ideally, I need to not change any pre-existing code to build it.
Every class to be used has the (pre-existing) attribute [MyPlugin] - is it possible to implicitly Export based on this attribute using RegistrationBuilder or some other method? I've not been able to find any mention of how or if this is doable and it is preffered not to Export based on the interface (though I'll do this if I have to)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cant figure out what's your issue... Exporting your Plugins or importing them again?

Comment: Since It's MEF, the plugins need to be tagged as exports (some ways of doing this implicitly) before they can be imported by the plugin manager using [Import]. The problem im having is with implicit exporting rather than use of the [Export] Attribute - i need to be able to import the classes without changing them, but to do that, they need to be exports

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with `RegistrationBuilder` - just have the predicate to only choose types that have the `MyPlugin` attribute:

```
var builder = new RegistrationBuilder();
builder.ForTypesMatching(t => t.IsDefined(typeof(MyPluginAttribute)) &&
                              typeof(IPlugin).IsAssignableFrom(t))
       .Export<IPlugin>();
```

The first condition is really what matters - the second one just avoids exceptions in case you've mistakenly marked a class that doesn't implement `IPlugin` with the `[MyPlugin]` attribute.